# Script to Change texture

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

Does anybody know of a way to script a change in texture to a blender object such as a wall. More precisely I have found ways to do it using images but I would like to use the built in textures in blender that can be found in the shading view under Add > Texture. For example if I have already assigned the brick texture to my wall how can produce a script to assign the Checker Texture.

Thank you for your help.